# Why sklearn Random Forest takes the same time to predict one sample than n samples

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, runtime, random-forest

I'm using sklearn on Python 3.6 and I noticed that it takes the same run time to predict one single sample as a 1D numpy array than n samples as a 2D numpy array with Random forest (~0.1 sec both). It looks like sklearn takes a certain time to set up the trees at each prediction step first and does the prediction instantly after. This could explain why the runtime for prediction of a large 2D array is the same as a 1D array?

here is my code for training the model:

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1, #or > 1 
        n_jobs=-1,
        random_state=2,
        max_depth=15,
        min_samples_leaf=1,
        verbose=0,
        max_features='auto'
        )

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

with open('classifier.pkl', 'wb') as fid:
   cPickle.dump(clf, fid)
```

In my case, I have to real-time-predict one by one in a loop like it:

```
with open('classifier.pkl', 'rb') as fid:
   clf = cPickle.load(fid)

for s in samples:
   #my feature extraction method
   pred = clf.predict(feature) #feature is a 1D np array containing features 
                               #computed for the sample s
```

Is it because I'm using it in the wrong way? Or is sklearn just not optimized for one by one prediction?

Comment: Are you sure that the runtime you're measuring isn't dominated by unpickling the classifier?

Comment: Yes, I notice the same problem by predicting just after the training step without using pickle.

Comment: `max_depth` is set to 15. That could be one reason it's slower. Second, your feature extraction method might also be time-consuming. One of the two in my op.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, `sklearn` is heavily optimised for vector operations. You are using it correctly. You should see a significant speed up if you do something like this:

```
features = np.zeros((len(samples), n_features))
for i, s in enumerate(samples):
   features[i] = feature_extraction(s)
preds = clf.predict(features)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) interesting, but in my case, I have to compute the features and predict "on the fly", so I have to make prediction into the loop of features computation. Should I conclude that sklearn isn't the right tool for this application? Should I re-implement the trees?

Comment: Another fact is that's working in my case (~0.002sec for runtime) with a sklearn Random Forest of only one tree but not with more than one (~0.1sec).